# Please explain this behaviour of switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

> Output:
>
> case0
>
> case1
>
> case2
>
> casedef

I understand that the default case is running because there is no break statement executing inside of the switch statement.

But I don't understand why case 1 and 2 are running when 0!= 1 and 0!=2

Also if I write switch(1) instead of switch(0) then only case 1 and 2 run which is understandable since 1!=0 and 1=1, 1=2 (in boolean? because non zero number denotes truth, but I am not sure, please correct me)

```
int main(){
    switch(0){
        case 0:     printf("case0\n");
        case 1:     printf("case1\n");
        case 2 :    printf("case2\n");
        default :   printf("casedef\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because all the statements following a matching case execute until a break statement is reached.

Comment: If you wonder why, see: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162574/why-do-we-have-to-use-break-in-switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch cases "fall through" to cases that are under them. You're seeing the mentioned behavior because cases for 1, 2 and default are all *underneath* 0. When you're switching on 1, you see 2 and the default because they're both underneath 1.

If you want to avoid falling through, you need to explicitly `break` out of the switch at the end of each case:

```
int main(){
    switch(0){
        case 0:     printf("case0\n"); break;
        case 1:     printf("case1\n"); break;
        case 2 :    printf("case2\n"); break;
        default :   printf("casedef\n"); break;
    }
}
```